# Accessing bash associative array using variables

Tags: bash, associative-array

I have spent a few hours on this now and can't seem to find a solution.

I have set three associative arrays in code:

template1
template2
template3

This could really be n number of arrays and a counter variable is also set in code so that:

```
template_name="template$counter"
```

Would give the next template to create. So my issue is when I want to loop over n number of associative arrays, I need to do something like:

```
for (( i = 1; i < $counter; i++ )); do
  template_name="template$i"
    for i in ${!template_name[@]}; do
      echo "$i - ${template_name[$i]}"
    done
done
```

But it does not work - I get bad substitution errors. It seems that I can;t use a variable name to access associative arrays dynamically. Is there any other way to look at this problems ?

Comment: You should either: (1) rethink your design or (2) change language. Doing this stuff in [tag:bash] is not really advised.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after some more digging:

```
eval echo "APP_NAME $template_name: "\${${template_name}[APP_NAME]}
```

Comment: I know - but I am stuck with bash here at work and can't find another method to achieve the outcome I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is want you expected but I think it can help you find a better solution than using eval.

```
#!/bin/bash
template0=( "123" "456" )
template1=( "zxc" "edc" )

counter=2
for (( i = 0; i != $counter; ++i )); do
    template_name="template$i[@]"
    echo ${!template_name}
    for j in ${!template_name}; do
        echo "$j - template$i"
    done
done
```

Produces:

```
==> 123 456
==> 123 - template0
==> 456 - template0
==> zxc edc
==> zxc - template1
==> edc - template1
```